# add_custom_target() can't create antlr4_runtime target because it already exists?

Tags: c++, cmake, antlr, antlr4

In my current project I have two sub-projects that use ANTLR4. My main CMakeLists.txt in root directory looks like this:

```
add_subdirectory(project1)
add_subdirectory(project2)
```

both project1 and project2 have this CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../cmake)
add_definitions(-DANTLR4CPP_STATIC)

set(ANTLR4_TAG 4.13.1)
set(ANTLR4_ZIP_REPOSITORY https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/archive/refs/tags/4.13.1.zip)
set(ANTLR_EXECUTABLE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../external/antlr4-4.13.1-complete.jar)

find_package(ANTLR REQUIRED)
include(ExternalAntlr4Cpp)
include_directories(${ANTLR4_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# The name is different for different projects: for ex project1lang project2lang etc
antlr_target(ProjectLang ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ProjectLang.g4
        VISITOR
        PACKAGE Lang)
include_directories(${ANTLR_ProjectLang_OUTPUT_DIR})

include_directories(..)

add_library(project STATIC files)
```

Now whenever i try to build the project I get this error:

```
CMake Error at /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:4007 (add_custom_target):
  add_custom_target cannot create target "antlr4_runtime" because another
  target with the same name already exists.  The existing target is a custom
  target created in source directory
  "/path/to/project2/".  See documentation for policy
  CMP0002 for more details.
```